# NGINX rewrite rule using two variables

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to achieve this but don't know how, or if it is possible:

`web.com/anything` => if `web.com/show.php?query=anything`

`web.com/anything/something` => if `web.com/show.php?query=anything&query2=something`

I mean , if there's only one variable it rewrites to web.com/variable

If there's a second variable, the first one turns into a folder now => web.com/variable/variable2

Comment: And what do you want to do with the request like `web.com/anything/something/more`? Or `web.com/anything/something/even/more`? What do you want to do with the existing query string, if there is any?

Comment: nothing really :P , just a 404

Answer (score 0):

Just did it !!

Was more simple that I've imagined..

`rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ show.php?query=$1&query2=$2 last;`